# Not able to extract exact text using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to get the text "7 days ago" from the following html using xpath.
Using the xpath `//div[contains(@class,'fnt20')]` I am able to get to the text within the div but I want to get to the exact text after the span ie. only the text "7 days ago" .
The html is as follows:

```
<div class="fnt20">
   <span class="accessibilityOnly">Duration:</span>
        7 days ago
</div>
```

Could anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `//div[contains(@class,'fnt20')]/text()[last()]` to get result '`7 days ago`'

Comment: Note that there is white space around `7 day ago`

Comment: If you want to truncate space use normalize-space()

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ups! I see this question is not tagged `php`. I should clearify that I'm using PHP

---

Although it is a little bit *fragile* the following code will work:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="fnt20">
   <span class="accessibilityOnly">Duration:</span>
        7 days ago 
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo trim($selector->query('//div[@class="fnt20"]/text()')
  ->item(1)
  ->nodeValue);
```

Note: The usage of `trim()` is not satisfying. But it works. I'll investigate how to avoid that, to get a *pure* xpath solution